# Compilación iOS no funciona

Tags: ios, xcode

Buenas tardes! Vengo desarrollando un proyecto en Game Maker Studio y he logrado que ambas computadoras se conecten (Windows y Mac), he exportado correctamente el proyecto, xCode lo ha recibido, he presionado "validate" y todo Ok y finalmente le he dado clic a "Upload to App Store". Luego, cuando me dirijo a iTunes Connect no logro visualizar ni agregar mi compilación o "build", me sigue saliendo este mensaje y no sé por qué. Será un error de Apple o mío? Porque no me ha rechazado nada, tan solo es que no puedo subir el build para darle a "Enviar para su revisión"

*Cabe mencionar que es la primera aplicación que subo.

[image: Este mensaje es el que sigue apareciendo:]

Gracias

Comment: hace un tiempo me paso, envie como 20 compilaciones y aun asi recibia el error, mas tarde me di cuenta de que mi aplicación tenia una libreria la cual era rechazada.

Comment: Hola sioesi! Gracias por responder. Dónde te diste cuenta que tenía una librería rechazada? Porque cuando le di a "Validar" la validó correctamente y se subió correctamente, pero en iTunes Connect no la encuentro. Ahora, también se reproduce correctamente en mi celular, pero en simulador no, podrá ser eso?

Comment: La verdad es que me di cuenta cuando tome contacto direcamente con apple PERO no llames por telefono ellos casi no ayudan. Envie un mensaje de contacto y ellos me explicaron el porque de que la compilacion no estaba disponible.

Comment: Perfecto, me contactaré con ellos. En cuánto tiempo te respondieron? Sabes si esto tendrá algo que ver? (adjunto imagen http://imgur.com/SRFtobM). Mi aplicación es sencilla y tan solo tiene un servidor en Hostinger que jala imágenes. En mi iPhone corre super bien, pero en el simulador cuando entra a la app se queda una pantalla negra y me lanza un error, que no sé por qué sale si en el dispositivo físico está corriendo sin problema.

Comment: ¿Tienes Xcode configurado con tu firma/identidad/equipo?¿Archivas el proyecto antes de subirlo?¿Qué mensajes/errores te aparecen en Xcode al intentar subir el fichero?

Comment: Hola Álvaro! Gracias por responder! He desarrollado este juego/app en la plataforma Game Maker. Tengo una conexión remota entre ambos equipos (Windows y Mac), ambas se conectan perfectamente, el juego se ejecuta en mi iPhone y Mac y finalmente he logrado exportarlo. Tengo los certificados de desarrollador y distribuidor, un App ID, Devices y un provisioning profile (desarrollador y distribuidor). El bundle ID coincide en iTunes Connect y apenas lo exporté se abrió en xCode (8.2.1) una ventana que cuenta con pestañas de "Archives/Crashes". Mi aplicación figura y lo primero que hice fue...

Comment: Darle click a "Validate" y todo bien, luego le di a "Upload to App Store" y también corrió super bien, entonces, en teoría, después de esos pasos debería salir el botón "+" para agregar la build o compilación, sin embargo, desde el día de ayer (casi 15 horas) y no me aparece absolutamente nada. Cabe destacar que si vuelvo a darle a "Upload to App Store" me sale este mensaje: http://imgur.com/g0sdTmZ . Por otro lado, cabe destacar que en mi iPhone se reproduce sin ni un problema (0 errores), pero en simulador, se abre la app y queda pantalla negra con el siguiente error http://imgur.com/EPfIFb6

Comment: Cabe destacar que la app cuenta con un servidor en "Hostinger" y de ahí tan solo jala algunas imágenes y texto. Además en configuración de la App ID solo tengo marcado lo siguiente: http://imgur.com/SRFtobM , acaso tiene algo que ver el problema con eso? Muchas gracias por tu apoyo, pues la aplicación la ha desarrollado mi hermano que está en el colegio y estoy buscando la forma de ayudarlo con la publicación. Gracias nuevamente!

Comment: Pues la verdad si que es raro, a mí se me ve online en cuestión de minutos. Parece que algo está fallando por ahí y te diría lo mismo que sioesi: habla con ellos. Y buena suerte. Siento no haber podido ayudar más.

Comment: Crees que sería buena opción crear una nueva bulos y subirla de nuevo?